# Tabify Form not showing up properly in Modal Dialog

Tags: sharepoint-list

I implemented HillBillyTabify and it works fine (See A below), except when I try to access the form using a promoted links webpart in modal dialog (see B below). The modal dialog form has scroll bars.

I tried using F12 to figure what CSS is causing the form to not show up, but hitting a wall.

A: [image]

B: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was able to make it work, although crude and more than likely not the appropriate way.

I would have liked for the SP.ModalDialog to have auto-resized to allow the HillBillyTabifyForm to open up correctly.

I placed the below code into a script editor web part on the page where the ModalDialog occurs.

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-dlgFrameContainer {
    padding-left: 0px !important;
}
.ms-dlgContent {
    left: 443px !important;
    top: 20px !important;
    width: 1075px !important;
    height: 775px !important;
}
.ms-dlgFrame {
    width: 1075px !important;
    height: 775px !important;
}
.ms-dlgTitle {
    width: 1025px !important;
}
#contentRow {
    padding-top: 0px !important;
}  
</style>
```

Of course it affects the "Working on it..." ModalDialog as well for that page when I click on the "New Form" from the promoted link.

Here's how it looks now:

[image]

And as you can see, the ModalDialog doesn't dynamically resize with the content.

Comment: Update: I had to remove the following code: `left: 443px !important;` from `.ms-dlgContent`. It was causing my ModalDialog to be fixed and I could not move it around on the screen.